# Is there a simple SQL example for Apache Ignite?

Tags: sql, ignite

I am trying to learn Apache Ignite and SQL and could not find simplest example. All examples seems bloated code with 10s of libraries needed before getting started.

Looking for complete Hello World (e.g. just pom.xml file and another 1 java file, not dependency of dependencies). I found several Github codes but they seem too big and complex for start.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite package contains `examples` folder which is a standalone Maven project. Among others, it has a `CacheQueryExample`.

Comment: Downloaded binary Ignite 2.0.0 and from apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin folder ran command ('mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryExample.java"').
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project ignite-examples: An exception occured while executing the Java class. src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryExample.
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException`

Comment: I would recommend to open a project in your favorite IDE, explore the code and JavaDoc, and run examples as instructed there. This will give much better insight on how to use Ignite.

Comment: BTW, even if you really want to run from command line with Maven, then you need to provide class name instead of file path, and run it from examples folder where corresponding pom.xml resides. Refer to Maven docs for details, you're clearly using it wrong.